# c programming, read a string from File IO and calculate the length of that

Tags: c, string, file-io, string-length, blank-line

I wrote the following code to read the first line of the text file and calculate the size of that string, but the calculated size is 1 number greater than the real size that I see on the text file. For example, this string: SAM, my code calculates the size 4; however the size of SAM is 3 or for Hello my code calculates the size 6, I'm wondering what is wrong with my code:

```
FILE * inp = fopen("name.txt", "r");
char nameArr[30];

fgets(nameArr, 30, inp);

int i;

for(i = 0; nameArr[i] != '\0' && nameArr[i] != '\n'; ++i)
{
}

if(nameArr[i-1] == ' ')
    --i;
printf("i is %d\n", i);

fclose(inp);
```

I think the problem if here `if(nameArr[i-1] == ' ')` but I cannot fix it

Comment: So do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and trace it as it runs to see why/where the extra increment comes from. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Does *anyone* ever read [the online documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) anymore about how to post formatted code before just splaying text into the editor and hitting the post button ?  Regardless, `I` is never set to any value, and is the only thing printed. That by itself invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use `strlen(nameArr)`?

Comment: You declared the variable `I` but then used the variable `i` in the loop. C is case-sensitive, they're not the same variables.

Comment: when I use 'strlen(nameArr)' the calculated size is 2 numbers greater than the real size, so I used for loop to remove '\n' from the end. I think when I read a string from the file it comes with one white space and one '\n'

Comment: when I run your code with file withe first line "6 5 6" I get the answer 5, that seems correct to me. Whats the problem? You dont need that `=' '` stuff

Comment: Best guess -- you have CR (carriage return -- `'\r'`) characters in your text file from windows or some such that you're seeing (and counting).  That's almost always the source of this kind of off-by-one error.

Comment: Your condition should be  nameArr[i] != '\0' && nameArr[i] != '\n'&&  nameArr[i] != '\r' as @ChrisDodd mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you mean

```
 int i; <<<=== i here

for(i = 0; nameArr[i] != '\0' && nameArr[i] != '\n'; ++i)
{
}

if(nameArr[i-1] == ' ')
    --i;
printf("i is %d\n", i);  <<<=== i here
```

There must be another i declared somewhere too, in which case change the name of this i something else

Comment: And also change the declaration `int I;` to `int i;`

Comment: 'actually, i is lower case in my main code but when I wanted to post it here I made a mistake and wrote "int I" instead of "int i" , but now I edited my question '